# PHP session not working in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

Heey people, in the following code my session is not working in IE. i dont know why cause to me there is nothing wrong.

browser.php // here php looks for on what browser your opening the page on:

```
<?php
session_start();


if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Gecko') )
{
   if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Netscape') )
   {
     $browser = 'Netscape ';
   }
   else if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') )
   {
     $browser = 'Firefox';
   }
   else if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome'))
   {
       $browser = 'Chrome';
   }
   else if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari'))
   {
     $browser = 'Safari';
   }
}
else if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') )
{
   if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') )
   {
     $browser = 'Opera ';
   }
   else
   {   
     $browser = 'Explorer';
   }

}
else
{
   $browser = 'Others browsers';
}


$_SESSION['Ibrowser'] = $browser;
?>
```

Print.php // this is a page where i want to print a pdf due to an iFrame

```
<?php
session_start();
include("Browser.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>wk demo</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript">
function printTrigger(elementId) 
{
    var browser = '<?php echo $_SESSION['Ibrowser']; ?>';
    var iFramePdf = elementId;
    /*alert("hello world");*/
    if(browser == "")
    {
        alert("session is leeg");
    }
    else
    {
        if(browser == 'Explorer')
        {
            //alert("IE");
            window.frames[iFramePdf].focus();
            window.frames[iFramePdf].print();           
        }
        else if(browser == 'Safari')
        {
            //alert("Safari");
            window.frames[iFramePdf].focus();
            window.frames[iFramePdf].print();           
        }
        else if(browser == 'Chrome')
        {
            //alert("Chrome");
            var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId); 
            getMyFrame.focus(); 
            getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
        }
        else if(browser == 'Firefox')
        {
            //alert("Firefox");
            window.open('http://62291.ict-lab.nl/Stage/VDMdm/pdf.php');
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Onbekende Browser");
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong in IE?

Comment: Are you certain, the file you include **Browser.php** is not **browser.php**?

Comment: How about removing space at the end of opera `$browser = 'Opera ';
`

Comment: its not making my session for the IE browser in print.php. Browser.php is working just fine nothing wrong with it. but in print.php it says the session>Ibrowser is empty :S

Comment: Look for javascript errors. Additionally if you're using cookies for the session, check if the cookie is set.

Comment: I've had this issue lots of times, and never really found a working solution - I always end up reverting to GET variables or hidden form inputs (which I don't like doing).

Answer (score 4):

IE has issues with cookies and handling iFrames due to [P3P (Platform for Privacy Preferences)](http://www.w3.org/P3P/). One [solution](http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies) I found is to include this header in every page that uses cookies:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Give that a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Solved my issue, thanks very much!  However it might be worth checking here: http://www.p3pwriter.com/lrn_111.asp exactly what the header codes mean.  You don't want to be declaring things about your privacy policy that aren't actually true.  Initially I copied and pasted this but after researching the codes found I only needed: header('P3P:CP="NOI NID"');  - because my site did not collect any Identifiable information